# Postgresql trigger - get all changed rows after transaction

Tags: postgresql, trigger, transaction

I have invoice_item table and invoice table. I need to check total price of Order after each transaction. Since I still want to be able to change things, I need trigger after each transaction.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER invoice_check AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON invoice INITIALLY DEFERRED FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE invoice_total_price();
```

But this trigger is executed for each row. I believe it is waste of resources to check invoice for all changed row. I only need to get all the invoices which need to be checked.
I use django ORM where you cannot easily determine, which columns were changed. So column trigger is not the best thing I think.

EDIT:

Here is the code of invoice_total_price function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION invoice_total_price() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $trigger_body$
DECLARE
    invoice RECORD;
    sum_prices DECIMAL;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO invoice FROM invoice WHERE invoice.id = NEW.invoice_id;
    SELECT SUM(invoiceitem.price_vat) INTO sum_prices FROM invoiceitem WHERE invoiceitem.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id;
    IF invoice.total_price_vat != sum_prices THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invoice total_price_vat is not equal to sum of price_vat of its items';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$trigger_body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "check total price"? Please show us your code.

Comment: It sounds like you want `FOR EACH STATEMENT` triggers that have `NEW` and `OLD` as pseudo-tables. PostgreSQL doesn't support this (yet). There's a patch for 9.5 that might add it.

Comment: Why are you *storing* `total_price_vat`? This is redundant information.

Comment: `total_price_vat` in invoice simplifies a lot of things in other parts of app. I know that it is not the cleanest thing to do but it's better than joining  table invoiceitem every time I need this number.

Comment: Why not make a view?

Comment: Because django ORM doesn't support views in the current version.